# calling a static function of service class from application class in android

Tags: java, android

lets say I have a service

```
class MyService extends Service {
..
public static void myStaticClass(Myobj someObj) {
       // do something
}
}
```

and Application class

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
..
  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    MyService.myStaticClass(someObj);
}
```

I would like to know if this is possible and what are the best practices to achieve similar result. My goal is to set something without starting the service.

Comment: Calling a `static` method won't in any sense create or initialise the `Service`. In this case, you're just using the `Service` class as a place to store your method, which is fine.

Comment: Oh I guess that answers my question then, do you think if this is a bad design overall or is  it just fine to do this way. If there any alternative please suggest. Thanks for your help @codebod

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is `IntentService`, that is a `service` you can start and will be finalized by itself after do the work.

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through Context.startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as
>   needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops
>   itself when it runs out of work.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService

Comment: Thanks, but my question is can I call a static function of service class from Application class like above? I dont want to start the service from application class

Comment: Yeah, you can't interact with a service without start it before. Maybe you can just use a regular class with a static method?